# Uncaught TypeError : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have noticed there's a few questions like this but none of the answers relate.

I'm trying to push values into an array although it's saying it cannot read properties of undefined every time I try to do this.

If I declare my array inside my click event as follows:

```
    $(#button).click(function(event){

array = [];

array.push(somevalues);

}
```

Then it works, but I want my array outside of my click event as inside my click event I'm trying to push values into the array. The above wont work as it sets the array to empty on each click.

If I set my array as follows at the very very start of the page:

```
    array = [];

 $(#button).click(function(event){

    array.push(somevalues);
    
    }
```

I get the error

```
Uncaught TypeError : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
```

Any ideas? I've tried so many different approaches, using let, const, var, inside different functions etc, but no luck.

I'm simply wanting to push one set of values into an array, and then another set of values at a later stage without the array resetting to empty.

Comment: There must be some code that changes `array` to some other value before the event listener runs.

Comment: Hey Vlaz, unfortunately there is 2 references to that entire array in my entire project. It's not being changed or set anywhere else.

Comment: It is. Computers only do what you tell them to. If a variable is changed, it's because there is code that changes it. It doesn't happen randomly.

Comment: I think you misunderstand Vlaz. My array is undefined outside the click function. So when I try to push to it, it says it's undefined.

If I move the array inside the click function it works, but each .push overwrites my current array as it's being set to = [] each click. That's why I want the array outside the click event.

Comment: I understand very well and I told you what the problem is. When you assign an array to the global and use it *immediately*, it's an array. If you define it outside, then *something changes it* before the click handler is reached. You cannot convince me that the assignment doesn't go through because that's *not* how JS works. If you do `console.log(array)` right after the assignment you'd confirm this. Are you done trying to convince me that JS works entirely differently for you and only you in the entire world?

Comment: I think it's I don't understand you then, apologies. I have defined the array outside the click event and when I console.log the array (outside the click event) it shows [] which is expected. Although once inside the click event it is undefined. I have done a search on my entire project for the array and it's only referenced twice.

This is a Cordova app, perhaps there is some differences? probably should have mentioned that...

I didn't mean to 'try and convince you Vlaz'... no need for hostilities :-) I appreciate your time to explain this to me.

Comment: All good! your first comment helped a lot with giving me an idea to use the event listener - thanks a lot Vlaz.